# AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am really stuck with this error and i read out same question and Apply solution but not solve my Error

So Please help me out this
Thanks in Advance

This is error

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Projects\sample_2.0\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:211: error: invalid color.

Command: C:\Users\SABC\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\81098111cca13a00241e3b8da7bcb924\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Projects\sample_2.0\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Projects\sample_2.0\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: What is in line 211 in C:\Projects\sample_2.0\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but for another resource. Maybe it was because I used AndroidX libraries. Anyway try to clean gradle cache, it was successful solution in my case. Just remove directory: **C:\Users\{username}\.gradle\caches\transforms-1**

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the solution. It works perfectly in my case too.